# Transform json data for DataTables

Tags: datatables

I have data which looks like this.

```
{
  "data": [
  { 
   "c1":  "datapt00",
   "size": 40
  },
  { 
   "c1":  "datapt001",
   "size": 80
  }
  ]
}
```

In HTML I am doing,

```
$(document).ready(function) { 
$('#example').DataTAble ( { 
"ajax": {
"url": "/data",
}} ); });
```

Is ther ean easy way to manipulate my data so its Datatable compliant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var jsonData = {
  "data": [
  { 
   "c1":  "datapt00",
   "size": 40
  },
  { 
   "c1":  "datapt001",
   "size": 80
  }
  ]
};
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "type": 'POST',
        "dataType": 'json',
        "url": '/echo/json/',
        "data": {
            "json": JSON.stringify(jsonData)
        },
        "dataSrc": "data"
    },
    "columns": [{
        "data": "c1"
    }, {
        "data": "size"
    }]
});
```

Working JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/70d01vo0/

Comment: what happens if I am not using jsonData. I am getting my data from "url"

Comment: Ah, bless you! There's no way of using AJAX on JSFiddle so this is the mechanism for getting json on JSFiddle. I think you'll probably be wanting to use something along the lines of `"ajax": {"url": "/data", "dataSrc": "data"}`. Hope that that makes sense and helps.